# How to get linked table details in dataview?

Tags: vb.net

I have two linked tables like this

[image]

Here myDataset.cat_table is already filled at form load,used  for other purpose, and me getting data from myDataset.prod_table by`dataview` by the below script.

```
       Dim myDataView As New DataView
       myDataView.Table = Me.myDataSet.prod_table
             For Each myRow As DataRow In myDataView.ToTable.Rows
                        Dim myId as integer
                        Dim myCatid as integer
                        Dim myCatName as object
                        Dim myprodDetails as object
                        myId = myRow("id")
                        myCatid = myRow("catid")
                        myCatName = ?
                        myprodDetails = myRow("details")
                   Next
```

Here in Dataview method, is it possible to get "myCatName" from the linked table? Me not looking for a separate query (by left join), because again i have to load query. And "Merge table" works for identical tables only i guess, So searching for other possible logics

Yours faithfully

Murulimadhav

Comment: title must describe the question only

Comment: i liked "Yours Faithfully"  ;)

Comment: I guess its posssible by JoinView sample custom DaveView class for VB.NET, link is http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B325682

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim myDataView As New DataView
    myDataView.Table = Me.myDataSet.prod_table
    For Each myRow As DataRow In myDataView.ToTable.Rows
        Dim myId As Integer
        Dim myCatid As Integer
        Dim myCatName As Object
        Dim myprodDetails As Object
        myId = myRow("id")
        myCatid = myRow("catid")
        Dim myCatPosi As Integer = cat_tableBindingSource.Find("id", myCatid)
        If myCatPosi >= 0 Then
            cat_tableBindingSourceBindingSource.Position = myCatPosi
            myCatName = cat_tableBindingSourceBindingSource.Current("title").ToString
        End If
        myprodDetails = myRow("details")
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, these two tables are not just data sets but if they can possibly be real database tables from sql, my suggestion is that you can easily manipulate the data of linked tables by SQL query. P.S - Import the following references.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Private strConn As String
Private sqlConn As New SqlConnection
Private sqlcmd As New SqlCommand

    Private Sub getdatatable()
        strConn = "Data Source= Server_Name;Initial Catalog= DB_Name;User ID= User_name;Password= Password"
        sqlConn = New SqlConnection(strConn)
        sqlConn.Open()
        Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT p.id, c.catname, p.products, p.details FROM cat_table c, prod_table p WHERE c.catid = p.catid", sqlConn)
        Dim myreader As SqlDataReader
        myreader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader
        myreader.Read()
        Do While myreader.HasRows
            'datagridview.Rows.Add(myreader.Item("id").ToString, myreader.Item("catname").ToString, . . . and so on as your desire table columns that you want to show on datagridview)
            Do While myreader.Read
                'datagridview.Rows.Add(myreader.Item("id").ToString, myreader.Item("catname").ToString, . . . same coding as above Do while looping)
            Loop
            myreader.NextResult()
        Loop
    End Sub
```

Trigger this method on Form_load or button click or whatever as you like. Before you do this type of showing in datagridview, you must **pre-define** the respective columns first in datagridview. I hope I will help you a little bit.